# How to apply a theme depending on Android version

Tags: android, themes

Currently I have a theme specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

Now I'm working to create the application backward compatible. As long as Gingerbread doesn't have `Theme.Holo.Light` I'll use `Theme.Light` but how to apply needed theme depending on OS version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use resource qualifiers for your values folder:

e.g. `res/values-v11`

Have your style reference `Theme.Light` in the standard `res/values/styles.xml`, then reference `Theme.Holo.Light` in `res/values-v11/styles.xml`. If it's running on API 11+, it will automatically choose Holo; otherwise, it will fall back to the standard `Theme.Light` specified in `res/values/styles.xml`.

Comment: +1 I would go with this answer. Otherwise you can write if-else to check sdk-version of device and accordingly apply theme.

Comment: `android:theme="@style/my_style_name"` should be something like that.